# How to call or trigger notification function in AppDelegate from ViewController or somewhere else?

Tags: swift, function, notifications, appdelegate

How could I call this kind of method which is inside `ViewController`, inside `appDelegate`or somewhere else:

```
func contactDelete(notification : NSNotification){}
```

And I gotta call it inside `appDelegate` inside

```
`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` here or inside other classes:



      func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.

            let tintColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 72/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1)
            window!.tintColor = tintColor

            if let aLaunchOptions = launchOptions { // Checking if there are any launch options.
                // Check if there are any local notification objects.
                if let notification = (aLaunchOptions as NSDictionary).objectForKey("UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey") as? UILocalNotification {
                    // Handle the notification action on opening. Like updating a table or showing an alert.
                    UIAlertView(title: notification.alertTitle, message: notification.alertBody, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
  let root : UIViewController = self.window!.rootViewController! as UIViewController
                let alertview = JSSAlertView().show(root, title: "Oops!", text: "Unable to add the new Contact, check contact permission from Settings.", buttonText: "Check it", cancelButtonText: "Nope", color: UIColor.init(red: 0.216, green:0.043, blue:0.129, alpha: 1))
                alertview.addAction(contactDelete)
                alertview.setTextTheme(.Light)


                }
            }
```

It needs some kind of extra argument but I do not know what argument. I even can't call it inside `viewDidLoad` method. I tried to trigger it like this but it won't work:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.contactDelete(_:)), name:DELETECONTACT, object: nil)
```

Comment: What kind of notification is the `contactDelete` function registered to handle?

Comment: @PhillipMills I am using LocalNotificationHelper so I use it inside 2 places. One place is where Notification action is and now I gotta use it inside the second function

Comment: What I'm getting at is: since it's designed to respond to a notification, why not send it one instead of trying to call it directly?

Comment: What do you mean? If I call it directly I have to make many notifications. I am also calling it like this inside ViewController 

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "contactDelete:", name: DELETECONTACT, object: nil)

Comment: @PhillipMills check my edit. This is the function

Comment: The sample in your comment isn't calling it.  It's just setting it up to respond to a *DELETECONTACT* notification.  If that has already happened, then you can execute the function with something like `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DELETECONTACT, object: nil)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114849/discussion-between-tarvo-maesepp-and-phillip-mills).

Comment: @PhillipMills huhh. My brain is crashing. Come chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114849/discussion-between-tarvo-maesepp-and-phillip-mills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Appdelegate code you are assigning RootviewController based on Notification arrived or simple launch using:

```
if let notification = (aLaunchOptions as NSDictionary).objectForKey("UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey") as? UILocalNotification {
```

But you are setting `NotificationViewController` as a `rootViewController` and you are `addObserver` on MainViewController so when you get notification and your rootView set as `NotificationViewController` you there is wont NSNotificationCenter created and you wont able to post it. so i suggest to create code like following:

Your appdelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let tintColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 72/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1)
        window!.tintColor = tintColor

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert , categories: nil))


        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("first") as UIViewController


        let navController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewControlleripad)
        navController.navigationBarHidden = true

        self.window?.rootViewController = navController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


        let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as! UILocalNotification!
        if (notification != nil) {


            runAfterDelay(2.0) {  // add 2 second delay of call method open notificationViewController from mainViewController
                self.FireNewViewControlelr(notification.userInfo!)
            }

        }
        return true
    }
```

Following is two method for calling NotificationViewController:

```
func FireNewViewControlelr(Value: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    print("userInf \(Value)")

    let navigationController: UINavigationController = (self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController)
    let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") as! NotificationViewController
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DELETECONTACT, object: Value)
    navigationController.pushViewController(initialViewControlleripad, animated: true)

}


func runAfterDelay(delay: NSTimeInterval, block: dispatch_block_t) {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}
```

If your app in background mode and you open app from notification banner tapped `didReceiveLocalNotification` look like following:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

        print("notification - tapped")

        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
            print("App already open")

        } else {
            print("App opened from Notification")


            runAfterDelay(2.0) {
                self.FireNewViewControlelr(notification.userInfo!)
            }

        }

    }
```

**Change code in following method:**

```
 func FireNewViewControlelr(Value: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        print("userInf \(Value)")

        let navigationController: UINavigationController = (self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController)
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : NotificationViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") as! NotificationViewController
        initialViewControlleripad.notificationInfo = Value
        navigationController.pushViewController(initialViewControlleripad, animated: true)

    }
```

in `NotificationViewController`

```
  var notificationInfo = [NSObject : AnyObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        print("data is \(notificationInfo)")


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func action(sender: AnyObject) {

         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DELETECONTACT, object: notificationInfo)
       self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```